# How to replace accent french character in filename with no accent character

Tags: mirth

I have a file reader channel on Mirth 3.50 that read a file on windows server and move it with ftp to a unix server. The filename on windows server has accent French character as follow:

PCSADTJAE2V-MCI-Liste_des_départs.pdf